# Tracking token ownership off chain?

Tags: wallets, nft, erc-721

I have a product that sells NFT's to users. I want to use custodial wallet to store all purchased NFT's but how I can track the owner of tokens off chain?

Comment: hi @bhushanlodha please follow up you have an answer here

Answer (score 0):

That's easy, you're the owner, you're the custodian.

---

If you would like to track the beneficial owner, you can use Excel, PHP, or any other technology you would like to record who you think should own each token.